# Stripe payment error Couldn't find Product with 'id'=@product.id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal, stripe-payments

Every time I test Stripe it gives me the error:

```
Couldn't find Product with 'id'=@product.id
```

This is my payment controller:

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
    def create
      @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
      @user = current_user
      token = params[:stripeToken]
      # Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
      begin
        charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
          amount:  product.price, # amount in cents, again
          currency: "usd",
          source: token,
          description: params[:stripeEmail]
        )
      rescue Stripe::CardError => e
        # The card has been declined
      end
      redirect_to product_path(@product), notice: "Payment processed successfully!"
    end
end
```

Comment: What's the full error?

Comment: `params[:product_id]` hast `@product.id` in it ?, so, your view is wrong.

Comment: Please share your view code.